# When importing time series without date (only hh:mm:ss) R decides to set all timestamps to 1899-12-31

Tags: r, date, datetime, timestamp, time-series

I have two datasets (xlsx-format) which I try to import. The two datasets contain temperature and light measurements with respect to time (in HH:MM:SS-format).

The measurements were done from 22:35:41 - 04:49:41, but when the time passes midnight the date doesn't get incremented. So the date stays at 1899-12-31. when I try to plot it I get this:
[image: R plot]

So what's happening here is that the first datapoints show up at the end of the plot and I really don't want to show the date either since it is wrong (I only want to show the hh:mm:ss -format)

I want it to look like this (done in Python with help from [@filbranden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9447571/filbranden) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60318410/plot-time-series-with-different-timestamps-and-datetime-time-format-that-goes-ov)):
[image: Right plot]

[Here is the link to the dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/bjoernjostein/temperature-and-light-data)

[Here is the link to an R-notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/bjoernjostein/time-stamp-problem)

Comment: Simple: If datetime < 1899-12-31 12:00:00 add 3600 * 24 to it.

Comment: Sounds right @[Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland), but how is that done in R? Do I have to for-loop through the Time-column and check the date and change it when **datetime < 1899-12-31 12:00:00** is fulfilled?

Comment: Something like `DF[DF$datetime < as.POSIXct("1899-12-31 12:00:00"), "datetime"] <- DF[DF$datetime < as.POSIXct("1899-12-31 12:00:00"), "datetime"] + 3600 * 24`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now tried to do as you said,[@Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland), and it worked.

Here are the code:

```
Temperature[Temperature$Time < as.POSIXct("1899-12-31 12:00:00"), "Time"] <- Temperature[Temperature$Time < as.POSIXct("1899-12-31 12:00:00"), "Time"] + 3600 * 24

Light[Light$Time < as.POSIXct("1899-12-31 12:00:00"), "Time"] <- Light[Light$Time < as.POSIXct("1899-12-31 12:00:00"), "Time"] + 3600 * 24

p = ggplot() + geom_line(data = Temperature, aes(x = Time, y = Temperature), color = "blue") + geom_line(data = Light, aes(x = Time, y = Light), color = "red") + xlab('Time') + ylab('Temp/Light')
print(p)
```

And here is the plot:

[image: The final plot]